# How to delete all files except specific type from the current date and day before cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Using cmd I want to delete all of the files in the directory except specific files for example .txt which are older than 2 days.

im unable to combine between forfiles and deleting everything beside a specific file type.

```
forfiles /p "C:\what\ever" /s /m *.* /D -<number of days> /C "cmd /c del @path"
```

where and how i can add the exception i want ?

Thanks !

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not positive about what you're wanting to do, but my best guess is that you just need to tell `ForFiles` to ignore that particular extension:

```bat
… "cmd /c if not @ext==0x22txt0x22 del @path"
```

Comment: Thanks ! it worked ! do you know how i can exclude specific files ? not only a file type ?

Comment: @Th15, there are many ways of performing tasks using batch files, however this extension to the question is too broad to be easily implemented into a single line `ForFiles` routine. _For that I'd suggest you start a new question, complete with a properly formatted [mcve] of your code and a replicable explanation of the problems it is exhibiting._ My question clearly shows how to exclude a type, which answers the question asked; it should be marked as accepted accordingly.